# how to select count in select condition mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

so i want to count the buyer who do transaction in january with the sum of the transaction is >= 600000, can you guys tell me the exact syntax, here's my syntax which are wrong:

```
select count in (select users_id, total_price_star_member from order_star_member where createdAt >= '2020-01-01' and createdAt < '2020-02-01' group by users_id having sum(total_price_star_member) >= 600000);
```

the point is i want to know how much the buyer who doing the transaction in january and the transaction is >= 600000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the right syntax for MySQL:

```
select count(*) from (select users_id, sum(total_price_star_member) from order_star_member where createdAt >= '2020-01-01' and createdAt < '2020-02-01' group by users_id having sum(total_price_star_member) >= 600000) inner_query;
```